# How Commas T oNumeric String in java

Tags: java

how to add commas  numeric string  for example I have this value 1000 and 1,000 I want you to return any suggestions.

```
public static String example(String number){  
        return number;
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html

Comment: i need value return 1,000 class String number have declared 1000

Comment: You need to pay more attention to what people are telling you. Yes, a number formater is about formatting a number ... but what exactly prevents you from turning your incoming string into a numger  to then use a number formatter to create any output format you wish?! Nothing; maybe besides your unwillingness to read what is recommended you to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick implementation i wrote.

```
public static String addCommas(String num){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=num.length();i>0;i=i-3){
        if(i-3>0)
            sb.insert(0,"," + num.substring(i-3,i));
        else
            sb.insert(0, num.substring(0,i));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: thanks works but you could give me some advice as you applied all

Answer (score 1):

EricGuan's answer can be improved upon by avoiding the creation of intermediate strings via `String.substring` and the concatenation in the call to `StringBuilder.insert`:

```
public static String addCommas(String num){
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(num);
  for (int i = num.length() - 4; i >= 0; i -= 3) {
    sb.insert(i + 1, ',');
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

However, there are caveats, both with this and Eric's implementation, principally that it doesn't handle negative numbers correctly, nor does it actually check that *it is a number at all*.

Sure, you can add make it do this, but it's simply more complicated than using `Integer.parseInt` (to check that it's really an integer), and then a `DecimalFormat` to yield the desired format:

```
public static String addCommas(String num) {
  return new DecimalFormat("#,###").format(Integer.parseInt(num, 10));
}
```